# Доступ к элементу списка System::Collections::Generic::List с++\cli

Tags: c++-cli

Имеется список элементов

```
System::Collections::Generic::List<ComboBox^> cBox;
```

Не знаю как обойти в цикле все элементы. У контейнера List есть метод:

```
ForEach(Action<T>^ action)
```

Только непоятно что передать в параметрах.
Хочу увидеть что-то вроде:

```
std::list<string>::iterator iterator = cBox.begin();
while (iterator != cBox.end())
{
   //work wish iterator 
   iterator ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GetEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344752.aspx) + MoveNext.

Но для стандартных коллекций можно использовать [for each](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes).

Comment: С помощью форич не получается.

     ComboBox^ comboBox;
     for each (comboBox, cBox)
     {
         //work with comboBox
     }

И с помощью нумератора тоже:
     
     System::Collections::Generic::List<ComboBox^>::GetEnumerator Enumerator = cBox.GetEnumerator();

Пишет что error C2065: Enumerator: необъявленный идентификатор

Comment: >> С помощью форич не получается.

синий экран что ли показывает?

а с энумератором... А где написано, что тип будет `GetEnumerator`? Вы не видите несостыковки?

Посмотрите в msdn. Там явно прописан тип - `IEnumerator^`. Поэтому, как минимум, правильно писать так

     System.Collections::IEnumerator^ iter = cBox.GetEnumerator();

Comment: извините, тупанул с форич. все получилось, спасибо!

     for each (ComboBox^ comboBox in cBox)
     {
        сomboBox->Text = "SUCCESS";
     }